# Why are indices on columns with very few unique values not effective?

Tags: database

So, most database experts say it's not effective creating an index on a column with very few unique values, relative to the size of the table.

Based on how databases work internally (I know most databases store indices using a B-tree), why does a B-Tree with few unique values make searching inefficient?

Comment: Not sure if this is what was meant by the experts, but if an index does not have many unique values, it is not an effective search since you will have to linear search all the common values.

Comment: Technically, such index is called not 'selective'. Only profiling will tell whether or not it will be effective in each particular case. For few unique values, bitmap index may improve search efficiency at the price of slower updates - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index

Answer (score 22):

First, you need to understand how an index on a column works. In simple words it is nothing but,

> an ordered list of all possible values in the given column with a *pointer* back to the actual record in the database.

Since it is ordered, a binary search can be used against it, rather than a linear search, which improves performance over a large dataset.

Imagine then, your index as a phone book ordered by a column, say `last name`; but within the set of records with a similar `last name`, there isn't a common pattern or meaningful order for the records: they are ordered purely random. And say we need to search this record:

> Ike Smith 4783 Random Ave. Seattle, WA 98117

Since the phone book is ordered by `last name`, we need only to go to the `S`, then the `m`, then the `i`, etc. until we find `Smith`. And (hopefully) there are only a couple of records under `Smith` so we find the one we want fairly quickly.

Now, imagine you have a phone book ordered by `city` instead of `last name`. And within the records that match a given `city` there is no particular order. And so we try our search again. However, once we find `Seattle` (using a extremely sophisticated binary search) we are left with close to 620,778 records, which we *have* to check sequentially as they ordered completely random. We're stuck checking *every* single entry for the record we want.

This is what happens when you use a very common column as the base of your index: the binary search returns a very large set of possible records with which the database can't make any assumptions beyond the initial indexed column values, so it needs to check sequentially within the resulting set for a matching record.

If the phone book were instead ordered by `zip code` (a less common variable), then you might find yourself only searching for 18,623 records residing on `98117`.

Furthermore, a true phone book usually resembles a composite index: instead of just ordering by a single column (i.e. `last name`), the values within the resulting set are then ordered by another column (say `first name`), and then another (`middle name`?) so the search can be done sub linearly at every step until you find the record needed. It it basically an index within an index, where even if the first column is not that common, the combination with the second one provides a specific enough criteria that only a small set of records need to be search linearly.

Comment: AFAIK many database implementations first do the full index scan then a full table scan, not a back-and-forth, as it saves time on a more common situation of a few duplicates.

Comment: @hexafraction What if we don't search for a specific record, but for all records from a specific city. Isn't it still a good idea to create an index on that column?

Comment: Hence "very few values". If there are only two cities, you would still have to scan half the table to get your result. Sure, its a bit faster, but not orders-of-magnitude faster, like you would normaly expect from an indexed column.

Answer (score 3):

In a b-tree, the index is stored separately(at least on-disk) from the data. A search on a b-tree requires `O(log n)` for lookups, and another `O(1)` for the seek to the table itself.

When searching without the index, you encounter a large lookup time via scanning the table, namely `O(n)`. However, when matching results are stored throughout the table, the lookups on the index exceed(in terms of resources) the lookups by doing a table scan.

When you have many values that can match a query, you make a `O(log n)` lookup on the index and a seek to the table data itself. You then *almost* reach a table scan (since sequential lookups across most of the table are near a scan) so the small reduction of table scanning by the index is smaller than the waste searching the index itself.

More details:
The tree lookup and seek latency(on hard disks) where heads must be repositioned happens once for every match(with a naive index lookup approach) while a table scan simply happens once. Even if the data is clustered in the index, computation and scanning must take place and the query optimizer selects a table scan instead.

<sub>Pardon the poor organization of this post, I'm operating from lack of sleep</sub>

Comment: a b-tree is not a binary tree

Comment: @aaronman pardon the error. Concepts with regard to this question are quite similar, though. Complexity is also sme, luckily.

Comment: The complexity may be the same but they are totally different, you would never use a binary tree to index a database

Comment: Also you didn't seem to actually address why the non unique values make the structure inefficient

Comment: @aaronman At least how I see it, the lookup against the actual data area is the choking factor since in the OP's hypothetical situation the lookups saved in that area are so negligible that even the O(log n) search of the b-tree more than negates any of that efficiency increase.

Comment: Sorry it might just be me but I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: It's probably me but I'm basically attacking the fact that practically looking against a third or so of the data area is still close to a full scan due to overhead, and the index lookup wastes more than it saves on said scan.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the goal of the index is to provide faster than linear search by avoiding having to scan through a significant portion of the data in the table (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).  If many of the would-be indexed values are identical, the database has to scan a significant portion of the table even after a successful index lookup.

So an index that has few unique values would provide very little performance benefit independent of its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

When you have very few unique values the hash (if you use a hashtable) will be the same for many entries and provide no speed up. With a b tree many entries in the range will be very small. Basically one you run into non unique values you have to either return more entries as results or use more criteria to search the data base
Since a primary key is guaranteed to have all unique values it is often indexed
A good example would be to consider the worst case where all the values are the same, in a b-tree or a hashtable you gain no performance advantage by indexing the data

Answer (score 0):

What cracked this question for me was when I understood this:

**RLDR;**

It is only inefficient if you **don't include more columns** in the key of the index that **makes it more unique**. So if `Column1` is not that unique, combine it with another `Column2` that you will in most cases be used to bring your data down to a smaller set in a where clause. For instance if `Country` is not that unique, add `City` and maybe also `Suburb`.

**In Simple Terms:**

The reason why having **ONLY** a column with very few unique values is inefficient is because using the index to lookup a value will only reduce the data set by say "half" if there are only two unique values with a 50% distribution.

You may think that there is **at least half less records** to "scan" now. But the catch is the index will return a list of ROWIDs that need to be **individually picked** and **filtered**.

Since databases have been optimised to do a **"table scan"** of sequential records in the db, much faster than picking one record at a time in a arbitrary sequence. Picking only 50% of the records on a large table, could be much slower than just simply "scanning" the whole table from start to finish.

*(This is possible because the db engine will load a **complete data block** with many records from IO and scan it in memory. If it has to pick records it has to load a **block** and then pick (potentially) one record from it, and then have to load **another block** from IO for the next records to pick, it may even have to load the **same block many times** during this picking process.)*

This concept is well explained by [use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates)