# Is there any point in adding an index to a column if there will only be 2 unique values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've got a table with multiple pseudo-boolean columns, which are actually string columns with "Yes" or "No" as their value.

Should I call `add_index` for these columns, or is that only helpful for columns with variable values?

Comment: Indexes help very specific queries. Please add the queries you want to optimize. And yes, there are cases where indexes suit very well boolean columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details (i.e. what queries you are making, the distribution of the boolean data, how many rows there are in the table), I would suggest leaving out those indexes for starters and adding them in later based on performance metrics.

There are existing questions and answers that go into more detail, like these:

[Why are indices on columns with very few unique values not effective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309779/why-are-indices-on-columns-with-very-few-unique-values-not-effective)

[How effective is creating index on column having two types of values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471104/how-effective-is-creating-index-on-column-having-two-types-of-values-only)